# Error after calling local_setup.bat

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been trying to install ROS 2 Dashing Diademata - Patch Release 5 (ros2-dashing-20191213-windows-amd64.zip) using the binary package on Windows 10. I am following the guide provided in: https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Installation/Dashing/Windows-Install-Binary/. When running

> ```
> call C:\dev\ros2_dashing\local_setup.bat
> ```

to setup my environment I get the following output:

> ```
> [connext_cmake_module] Warning: The location at which Connext was found when the workspace was built [[C:\Program Files\rti_connext_dds-5.3.1]] does not point to a valid directory, and the NDDSHOME environment variable has not been set. Support for Connext will not be available.
>
> " set CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=C:\dev\ros_dashing was unexpected at this time.
>
> " set AMENT_PREFIX_PATH=C:\dev\ros_dashing was unexpected at this time.
>
> " set PKG_CONFIG_PATH=C:\dev\ros_dashing\lib\pkgconfig was unexpected at this time.
> ```

Issuing any command starting with ros2 (such as ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp talker) afterwards results in the following error:

```
failed to create process.
```

Could anyone give me some ideas on what might be going wrong here?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/342099/error-after-calling-local_setup.bat/) by [Kasper H](https://answers.ros.org/users/51069/kasper-h/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2020-01-20

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is not an error but a warning. The ROS packages that you installed include bindings for RTI Connext However this is a warning that if they do not find RTI Connext installed that the implementation will not be available because the underlying library is not available.

There are instructions for installing additional DDS implementations here: https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Installation/DDS-Implementations/

There's more documentation on how to use Multiple RMW implmentations (that usually build on top of the DDS implementations) here: https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Tutorials/Working-with-multiple-RMW-implementations/

But in general most users will usually use the default RMW implementation and can ignore the above message.

Related Questions https://answers.ros.org/question/323501/problem-with-ros2-installation/

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2020-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dickson](https://answers.ros.org/users/43223/dickson/) on 2021-08-11**:
I disagree. Am currently experiencing the error atm. This solution doesn't work.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2021-08-11**:
As with the other poster, there's likely also an additional error in your system in addition to the quoted warning. Please ask a new question of your own with all the information necessary to reproduce your environemnt, the full commands that you're running as well as the full console output produced.